# save bytes from Serial into ROM (EEPROM)

Tags: serial, string, eeprom

I am trying to save an incoming text from serial into the ROM of the Arduino using EEPROM. I found out that you can only save a byte at once. So I thought I could do it like that:

```cpp
#include <EEPROM.h>

byte c;
int i; // counter for addressing EEPROM

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); // Serial start
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available()){ // check if there is some input form Serial
    while(Serial.available()){ // loops through every character of the Serial input
      c = Serial.read(); // saves current character into variable c in byte form
      EEPROM.write(i, c); // saves c into rom with the address i (counts up after each character)
      i++; // counts c up
    }

    // after all characters are looped through and saved into EEPROM
    Serial.println(i); // print the amount loop runs / amount of characters that are saved
    Serial.println(EEPROM.read(0)); // prints the first character of the input that got saved into EEPROM
    Serial.println("--"); // print cut for overview
    i = 0; // resets counter to 0. That way all values are goint to be overwritten if you type something new into the serial monitor
  }
}
```

Unfortunately that is not working at all. So what did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to read back and print the byte you wrote with `EEPROM.read(i);` and not always read from address 0 with  `EEPROM.read(0);` as you have implemented the code?

Comment: Your code makes no sense whatsoever. You should start by learning how to read serial into an array (https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/) and then copy that resultant array byte-by-byte into the EEPROM.

Comment: it does make sense. I will command it. One moment

Comment: 1) i is used prior to being initialized.2) It assumes that all the data to be written has arrived and is sitting in the serial buffer already. Serial is slow so the chances are that it'll only get 1 byte each time it runs through that `while(serial.avalible())` loop. You're only ever going to write to address 0 (other than the first byte which will go to an undefined random location)

Comment: so how would you do something like this?

Comment: How about using the EEPROMex library. I find it very useful. Can even save a whole class/struct which can be easier to expand http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/EEPROMex. Your serial should read into a large enough array or struct member, such as char[20]. Then use EEPROMex to get or save the whole thing for you.

Comment: Thank you Visual Micro. That tip helps me a lot. I guess that is the solution :)